# Apple TV, xfinity, and remote app

Tags: iphone

I have my 3rd gen Apple TV connected to an xfinity hotspot (that's the only wifi I have right now) and the remote app from my iPhone 6 Plus S isn't finding it on the air play menu? They are both connected to the same xfinity hotspot. I can mirror air play but my remote app just won't find my Apple TV. I tried three different apps too and none of them are working.
Some help would be best appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the [NEW Apple TV Remote app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-tv-remote/id1096834193?mt=8)?

Comment: Yeah I've tried both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't say for sure, my "gut feeling" is that this is a firewall issue - your router could be blocking ports 3689 and/or 5353.

See also: [If the Remote app won't connect](https://support.apple.com/en-gu/HT201397)

Comment: How would I go about fixing the issue ?

Comment: As explained in the article, you would have to consult documentation for your router to open the ports. Generally, you configure a router by entering its IP address into a web browser. You can find the address in System Preferences, as described at http://osxdaily.com/2011/10/05/find-router-ip-address-mac/

Comment: What do I do when I have the IP address? The hotspot that I'm using is a public hotspot through XFINITY.

Comment: You have a public hotspot in your home? I have never heard of anything like that. If there is some program like that, then you will need to contact whoever administers the network. If it's not really a public hotspot, you will need to look up the instructions for your specific router.